# how to sum complicated condition in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have dataframe below;

```
df=pd.DataFrame(np.arange(1,19).reshape(6,3),columns=list('ABC'),index=list('acbabc'))

    A   B   C
a   1   2   3
c   4   5   6
b   7   8   9
a  10  11  12
b  13  14  15
c  16  17  18
```

I would like to conditional summing dataframe shown as below;

```
   A  B  C
a 11 13 15
b 20 22 24
c 20 22 24
```

each elements shows conditional sum of df.for instance,(I am inconfident about expression)

```
result.loc[0,0]=df.loc[df.A=="a"].sum()
```

how can I get this dataframe ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Groupby `index` and `sum` the columns should give you what you need:

```
df.groupby(df.index).sum()

#    A   B   C
#a  11  13  15
#b  20  22  24
#c  20  22  24
```

Comment: same answer `df.groupby(level=0).sum()` +1